# Unresolved Identifier for Function As Parameter

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I am writing a function which accepts a function as its parameter. Currently, the function gives an error for the unresolved identifier for the parameter's return tuple. The code I currently have:

```
func getMidPoints() -> (CGPoint,  CGPoint) {
   // code that calculates midpoint
    return (mid1, mid2)
}

func createSubPath(mid1: CGPoint, mid2: CGPoint) -> CGMutablePathRef {
    let subpath : CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, nil, mid1.x, mid1.y)
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(subpath, nil, previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y, mid2.x, mid2.y)
    return subpath
}

createSubPath(getMidPoints())

// Missing argument for parameter 'mid2' in call
```

I am not sure if I am properly utilizing functions as parameters. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try `func createSubPath(mid1: CGPoint, mid2: CGPoint) -> CGMutablePathRef {`

Comment: That is what I had originally, but I was getting a missing argument error. I have updated the code

Comment: `createSubPath(getMidPoints().0,getMidPoints().1)` or change your declaration to pass a tuple `func createSubPath(midPoints:(mid1: CGPoint, mid2: CGPoint)) -> CGMutablePathRef {`

Comment: Appreciate the help. It took: createSubPath(getMidPoints().0, mid2: getMidPoints().1). If you submit an answer, i'll accept

Comment: Neither of those accept a function as its parameter. The first has no parameter; the second has two parameters, both `CGPoint`s. The call to `createSubPath` doesn't pass the function `getMidPoints` but the result of calling it (which is a pair of `CGPoint`s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your method declaration to pass a tuple:

```
func createSubPath(midPoints:(mid1: CGPoint, mid2: CGPoint)) -> CGMutablePathRef {
    // your code 
}
```

or pass two parameters to your method:

```
createSubPath(getMidPoints().0, mid2: getMidPoints().1)
```